# Install Certain NPM Modules Globally?

Tags: node.js

I'm debating how I should setup certain node modules.

Lets say I have a folder called "Projects".  This will hold various code projects for node that I'll create under this going forward.

Now I can install stuff like cucumber, lodash, mocha, etc...stuff that **I know I'll probably use across most all my projects**:

**1)** npm install -g
- here, any package.json can find it on my PC I think

**2)** npm install [whatver] in the root of my "Projects" folder so that now I have an npm_modules folder sitting at the root so any projects created's package.json will able to find those type of modules at the root of my Projects folder
- here, I'd have to npm install once at the root of my Projects folder if not already installed globally and I didn't go with option #1

**3)** npm install into each project under projects.  But this seems like it's not efficient.  If I have to make people install stuff like cucumber every time they clone down a project, that means when they run npm install, it'll have to install cucumber again and again, for each project which seems stupid to me to do something like that if it's really a global package I plan on using across many projects

-- so here for example I might have several projects I create or clone:  Projects**MyProject1**, Projects**MyProject2**, and so on. Each of those projects has its own package.json of course looking for dependencies like cucumber, mocha, etc.  If I do it this way I'll have to wait for npm to install those into each's own node_module folder so for example `Projects\MyProject1\node_modules\cucumber`, `Projects\MyProject2\node_modules\cucumber` and so on.  Seems stupid and duplication all over to do that...?

Suggestions on which option is best and why you think that based on your experience managing projects in node?

Comment: About #1, globally installed packages aren't available in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > npm install -g - here, any package.json can find it on my PC I think

   This won't work because global modules cannot be picked up by `require` in your node scripts.
2. > npm install [whatver] in the root of my "Projects" folder so that now I have an npm_modules folder sitting at the root so any projects created's package.json will able to find those type of modules at the root of my Projects folder

   This will work for sure as long as the projects in your "Projects" folder will always be there. If you publish a project then the dependencies for that project will have to go with it.
3. > npm install into each project under projects. But this seems like it's not efficient. If I have to make people install stuff like cucumber every time they clone down a project, that means when they run npm install, it'll have to install cucumber again and again, for each project which seems stupid to me to do something like that if it's really a global package I plan on using across many projects

   Why is this stupid? As long as you do `npm install cucumber --save` then your dependency on `cucumber` will be saved to your project's `package.json` file. All anyone who clones your project should have to do is this:

   1. `$ git clone project.git`
   2. `$ cd project && npm install`

   `npm install` without any additional arguments will install all the dependencies listed in the `package.json` file for the project. It only has to do this once. After that all the dependencies are downloaded and installed within the `node_modules` directory for your project. The only time they'd need to run `npm install` again from the root of the project directory would be if they deleted the `node_modules` folder or you made a change and added a new dependency to `package.json`.

---

Installing modules in your "Projects" directory will make them available to any scripts `require`ing the module from within any subdirectories. Keep in mind that if I were to clone your repository I won't have your "Projects" directory. I'll just have the directory for your project, wherever I cloned it to. I need to get those dependencies somehow and the easiest way is for me to `cd` into the project and run `npm install` where you should have a `package.json` file that lists all the required dependencies.

PS - `npm install [module-name] --save` only saves the dependency version if you already have a `package.json` file in the root of your project. If you don't have one yet, then initialize one first.

```
$ npm init
```

Comment: ok cool I just thought that if the majority of our projects are using cucumber, that it would be a pain to have devs download multiple installs of cucumber per each project and have duplicate sets in node_modules folder.   meaning each project's node_modules would have it's own cucumber folder seemed like a lot of redundancy to me...rather than have a top level folder in the ROOT of your projects folder but that probably causes more confusion rather than devs just cloning and doing an npm install period

Comment: yea I know about the init.  I plan on checking in the packages.json so when the clone it'll be there of course.

Comment: "This will work for sure as long as the projects in your "Projects" folder will always be there".  What do you mean?  As long as the developer myself or whoever has [RootProjectsFolderName]\npm_modules then any Projects below this with a package.json files will be able to find that npm_modules folder, is that what you mean?  It's just that that it'd be on the developers to know the convention we use is to install a bunch of modules in the root of [MyProjectsFolder] first...then go and clone down projects to the folder

Comment: Yes. If I clone one of your projects I will not have a parent projects folder with all these global dependencies you speak of. I would expect your package.json to have a dependency manifest and automatically install them all when I run `npm install` from within your project directory.

Comment: so there's no point in doing what I was thinking, having a root npm_modules folder at all!  If I'm exposing it to other devs, the usual like you said is that everyone just runs npm install no matter what and you have its own set of those modules per project so then why would anyone want to use -g also (first option)?  Seems pointless if you really want your projects to be portable and cloneable right?  Does anyone really do -g?  Plus if you can't require it seems useless.  Just wondering what use case there is for -g then

Comment: Yes and there are multiple reasons for that. One is that any of your projects could get locked into one of its dependencies. In other words, say you've coded up a big app in one project and use a module pretty extensively all over the place. Now that module releases a new major version and it will take some effort for you to refactor your project against the new API. Do you want to be stuck using the old version in other projects where there would be no downside to just using the latest version? If each project has their own dependency manifest, that's never an issue.

Comment: You could take as long as you needed to refactor/upgrade the big project while using latest versions of the hypothetical module in other projects. Also, npm isn't really designed to work the way you're talking anyway. You'd actually be creating more work for devs with your projects because they'd have to clone all your projects and then manually install ALL of the dependencies into a parent directory instead of just running one command after `git clone`.

Comment: Not to mention most build systems that deploy your apps into production will try to run `npm install` from within the project directory during publication. I think you'll just be happier sticking with the typical node/npm conventions ;). Put `node_modules` in your `.gitignore` and check in a `package.json` file listing all your dependencies.

Comment: makes me also wonder if anyone really truly does or wants to use something like "latest" in package.json.  If I have an app that works well with certain versions of Node, cucumber, mocha, whatever, do I ever really want to have something like "cucumber" : "latest" in my package.json?  Or do I always want specific versions stated for my dependencies period

Comment: It all depends. I maintain lots of apps. Some I care to keep updated and pull down new features of the modules I'm using. Some apps aren't important enough for that kind of maintenance. Always list specific versions in package.json though. Even you plan to have latest versions of your dependencies regularly, you don't want new versions getting pulled in just because you did an npm update and it pulled in a totally incompatible new major version. Upgrading dependencies should be manual, or with a tool like [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates).

Comment: Upgrading dependencies should be a very conscious decision. If you let npm manage the version numbers by installing modules with `npm install module-name --save` then you're good to go. It uses a version listing that allows `npm update` to pull in new minor and patch version updates for a module, but does not automatically allow major version updates.

Comment: The `npm-check-updates` module will look in your package.json and tell you if any of your listings have updates on the registry that you don't have. It's good for determining if some module has a major update so you can investigate and decide if it's worth the trouble. Some updates come with HUGE performance boosts so there are definitely pros and cons to all major version updates and you'll have to decide for your apps when the time comes.

Comment: I really appreciate your insight and time to reply.  Thanks a lot!  I'm new to node, coming from .NET.  Finally away from Microsoft for good now :)

Comment: That's for dependencies you only need installed if you're a developer on the project, like mocha. `npm install mocha --save-dev` is the same as --save except the dependency will only be installed when someone does `npm install` inside the project directory. Your deployment server on the other hand likely doesn't care about your dev dependencies and only wants the ones needed to run in production, so your deployment server would do `npm install --production` instead and ignore all dev dependencies. Speeds up build deployment time.

Comment: I was a .NET guy for eight years! Feels good to do something different ;)

Comment: f yea it does.  I find that everyone outside .net cares more about testing as well, especially TDD which I am obviously a huge user of

Comment: I feel like it's because of the way .NET tries to abstract everything away from the developer instead of trying to more intuitively teach them how things work. But I digress, these comments aren't for extended discussion. Feel free to add me on Google hangouts. Alex.ford@codetunnel.com